# Update an item's attributes while in cart

Tags: magento-1.9, product, cart, configurable-product, product-attribute

Just want to preface this in saying that I'm extremely new to Magento/module development.  What I'm trying to do is update an item's attributes(color,size,etc.) while in the cart without going back to the product page.  So far I've used this as a starting point:
http://inchoo.net/magento/updating-options-of-configurable-product-that-is-already-in-the-cart/

I realize that this is very old code and will not work with Magento 1.9, which I am currently on.  So far this is what I have:

```
<?php
$_item = $this->getItem();
$isVisibleProduct = $_item->getProduct()->isVisibleInSiteVisibility();
$canApplyMsrp = Mage::helper('catalog')->canApplyMsrp($_item->getProduct(), Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Attribute_Source_Msrp_Type::TYPE_BEFORE_ORDER_CONFIRM);
?>
<tr>
    <td class="product-cart-image">
        <?php if ($this->hasProductUrl()):?>
            <a href="<?php echo $this->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getProductName()) ?>" class="product-image">
        <?php endif;?>
            <img src="<?php echo $this->getProductThumbnail()->resize(180); ?>" alt="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getProductName()) ?>" />
        <?php if ($this->hasProductUrl()):?>
            </a>
        <?php endif;?>

        <ul class="cart-links">
            <?php if ($isVisibleProduct): ?>
                <li>
                    <a href="<?php echo $this->getConfigureUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $this->__('Edit item parameters') ?>"><?php echo $this->__('Edit') ?></a>
                </li>
            <?php endif ?>

            <?php if ($this->helper('wishlist')->isAllowInCart() && $isVisibleProduct) : ?>
                <li>
                    <a href="<?php echo $this->helper('wishlist')->getMoveFromCartUrl($_item->getId()); ?>" class="link-wishlist use-ajax"><?php echo $this->__('Move to wishlist'); ?></a>
                </li>
            <?php endif ?>
        </ul>
    </td>

    <td class="product-cart-info">

        <a href="<?php echo $this->getDeleteUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $this->__('Remove Item') ?>" class="btn-remove btn-remove2"><?php echo $this->__('Remove Item') ?></a>

        <h2 class="product-name">
        <?php if ($this->hasProductUrl()):?>
            <a href="<?php echo $this->getProductUrl() ?>"><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getProductName()) ?></a>
        <?php else: ?>
            <?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getProductName()) ?>
        <?php endif; ?>
        </h2>

        <div class="product-cart-sku">
            <span class="label"><?php echo $this->__('SKU'); ?>:</span> <?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_item->getSku()); ?>
        </div>

        <?php if ($_options = $this->getOptionList())?>

        <?php
            if($this->getProduct()->isConfigurable()) {

            $_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($this->getProduct()->getId());
            Mage::getBlockSingleton('catalog/product_view_type_configurable')->unsetData();
            $_configurable = Mage::getBlockSingleton('catalog/product_view_type_configurable')->setData('product', $_product);
            $_cdata = json_decode($_configurable->getJsonConfig());
            $_current = array();

            foreach((array)$this->getOptionList() as $_option) {
                $_current[$_option[‘label’]]=$_option['value'];
            }
            foreach($_cdata->attributes as $attribute) {
            ?>

            <strong><?php echo $attribute->label; ?></strong>
            <select name="cart[<?php echo $_item->getId() ?>][option][<?php echo $attribute->id ?>]">
            <?php foreach($attribute->options as $option) { ?>
            <option <?php echo ($_current[$attribute->label]==$option->label) ? ' selected' : '' ?> value=<?php echo $option->id ?>><?php echo $option->label ?> </option>
            <?php } ?>
            </select>
            <?php } } else { 

        } ?>
```

The above is what is in default.phtml

```
<?php

    class MyModule_EditInCart_Model_Card {

        public function update($e) {
            $_this = $e->cart;
            $data = $e->info;

            foreach ($data as $itemId => $itemInfo) {
            $item = $_this->getQuote()->getItemById($itemId);

            if (!$item) continue;
            if (!isset($itemInfo['option']) or empty($itemInfo['option'])) continue;
            $options = $item->getOptions();

                foreach ($options as $option) {
                    if($option->getCode()=='info_buyRequest') {
                    $unserialized = unserialize($option->getValue());
                    $unserialized['super_attribute'] = $itemInfo['option'];
                    $option->setValue(serialize($unserialized));

                    } elseif ($option->getCode()=='attributes') {
                        $option->setValue(serialize($itemInfo['option']));
                    }
                }

            $item->setOptions($options)->save();
            Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart')->save();
            }
        }
    }
?>
```

The above is what is in Card.php which is in my Model folder of my module.

Any help that could push me in the right direction would be really really appreciated.  I also know that there are pay modules that can do this, but using one of those isn't an option right now.

Thanks!